# How to zoom image by giving xy axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, zooming

I want to zoom an image by giving x and y axis. I have a thumbnail image and two input boxes, on which user will enter the co-ordinates and after clicking on submit button, the zoomed image should be appear.

I dont want to zoom image on mouse over,rather enter the axis and click on button

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/kaintyura/z78sL/`
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have, so far? And explain what different x, y co-ordinates should do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/juanojeda/nFByt/ this might help.

Comment: I want to make it functional, http://jsfiddle.net/kaintyura/z78sL/